# Electron Builder Vue cli 3 application on Windows throwing error registerStandardSchemes undefined

Tags: vue.js, electron, electron-builder

**Background**

We are building an Electron application and have been able to work on it, and build it using Linux and Mac OS. When we move it to a Windows machine in development or when build on a Mac OS machine then ran on the Windows machine, it fails.

When we follow the [instructions here](https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/) it says,

```
vue add electron-builder
yarn electron:serve
```

should run the application. On a fresh install using Windows this fails for us.

**Problem**

When we try and start the application on Windows we get an error,

> TypeError
>   electron__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.protocol.registerStandardSchemes
>   is not a function

**Example**

This line comes with the boilerplate when we add Electron Builder to the app that seems to be throwing the error.

```
protocol.registerStandardSchemes(['app'], { secure: true })
```

It is being used like this,

```
import { protocol} from 'electron'
protocol.registerStandardSchemes(['app'], { secure: true })
// Helper to create our main view BrowserWindow
function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })

  if (process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    // Load the url of the dev server if in development mode
    win.loadURL(process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL)
    if (!process.env.IS_TEST) win.webContents.openDevTools()
  } else {
    createProtocol('app')
    // Load the index.html when not in development
    win.loadURL('app://./index.html')
  }
}
```

**What We Tried**

When I console.log protocol the only key available is, `registerSchemesAsPrivileged` which is in the docs but not what came with the boiler and nor does it work. I can see at [this page](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/protocol#protocolregisterschemesasprivilegedcustomschemes) that the `registerStandardSchemes` is referenced in a paragraph but it is not well explained in it's own section like the rest of the methods on that page.

**Question**

What does one need to do to access the method, `protocol.registerStandardSchemes(['app'], { secure: true })` when running an Electron-Builder application scaffold with Vue CLI 3 on Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue - if you're just looking to get back to development, running `vue add electron-builder` again fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks buddy, the problem was actually that the correct header for the newest version of that package had not been published so when node-pre-gyp tried to pull the header from the network it was getting a 404. Once I downgraded to a version that had a header at the correct URL path the header was pulled and rebuilt for electron as expected.